# Swift Facebook Login no url after logout

Tags: swift, facebook

I've implemented this in my app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login/
I've pretty much followed this to a tee, except that I have two view controllers with this implementation; one outside of a navigation controller for login (1), one inside of a navigation controller for logout (2).

I can login initially just fine, but after logout, going back to the view controller (1), after clicking "Continue with facebook", it just shows me a blank safari page.

When logging in for the first time, the url bar will show "facebook.com"
[image]

But after logout and when I want to re-login again, the url is just blank
[image]

May I know what I need to do? Thanks.

VC Code here: https://codedump.io/share/j1rxrJVMBw00/1

Edit: Login will open a navigation controller (indirectly), and logout will dismiss it. It seems like this is a cause of the problem but I'm not sure how.

Comment: can I watch your code

Comment: @Jaydip added a link to my code, thanks